# Как по при селекте таблички в поле записать последнюю секунду дня?

Tags: postgresql

Собираю статистику, а именно сколько человек находился на паузе. Следующим запросом:

```
select 
    agent_id,
    "event",
    cae.created_on_tz,
    to_char(cae.created_on_tz, 'yyyy-mm-dd') "date",
    LEAD(event) OVER (PARTITION BY cae.agent_id ORDER BY cae.created_on_tz) next_event,
    LAG(event) OVER (PARTITION BY cae.agent_id ORDER BY cae.created_on_tz) prev_event,
    LEAD(cae.created_on_tz) over (partition by cae.agent_id order by cae.created_on_tz) end_on_tz
from chat_agent_event cae                        
where agent_id = 2 
      and ("event" = 'PAUSE' or "event" = 'UNPAUSE' or "event" = 'DISCONNECT') 
      and (cae.created_on_tz between '2019-03-11' and '2019-03-12')
```

получаю такую таблицу

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Время считается между определенными парами событий, но это уже другая часть запроса.

Проблема возникает когда для последнего события **PAUSE** нет парного события. То есть специально смоделировал, когда на паузу встал в 23 часа вечером, а вышел с паузы уже на следующий день. В итоге я такие переходящие события не могу посчитать (по каждому дню выводится информация, не общее время за указанный диапазон)

Но я знаю, что если для последнего события **PAUSE** нет следующего события (**next_event is null**), сегодня, то оно явно переходящее, поэтому чтобы мне посчитать это событие, я могу в поле **end_on_tz** поставить допустим время '23:59:59'.

Вопрос, можно ли это как-то сделать?

**UPD**: доработал запрос, используя подсказку от Akina

```
select 
   agent_id,
   "event",
   cae.created_on_tz,
   to_char(cae.created_on_tz, 'yyyy-mm-dd') "date",
   LEAD(event) OVER (PARTITION BY cae.agent_id ORDER BY cae.created_on_tz) next_event,
   LAG(event) OVER (PARTITION BY cae.agent_id ORDER BY cae.created_on_tz) prev_event,                       
   LEAST(
        LEAD(cae.created_on_tz) over (partition by cae.agent_id order by cae.created_on_tz), 
        date(created_on_tz) + interval '1 day' - interval '1 second'
        ) end_on_tz                                                       
from chat_agent_event cae                        
where agent_id = 2 
and ("event" = 'PAUSE' or "event" = 'UNPAUSE' or "event" = 'DISCONNECT') 
and (cae.created_on_tz between '2019-03-11' and '2019-03-12')
```

Получил следующий результат
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: `LEAST(end_on_tz, date(created_on_tz) + interval 1 day - interval 1 second)`. Ну и при необходимости - поправка на NULL (CASE или COALESCE).

Comment: @Akina, SQL сругнулся, что не знает что такое **end_on_tz**, поэтому заменил на такую конструкцию ```LEAD(cae.created_on_tz) over (partition by cae.agent_id order by cae.created_on_tz)```  Сначала не совсем понял как работает эта конструкция ```date(created_on_tz) + interval '1 day' - interval '1 second'```, но потом разобрался

Comment: @Akina, а правильно ли будет если начало дня задам таким выражением `date(created_on_tz) + interval '0 second'`? Или это странновато выглядит

Comment: Ноль-то зачем плюсить? просто `date(created_on_tz)`.

Comment: То есть дата 2019-03-11 равносильна 2019-03-11 00:00:00?